# JQuery button takes url and submits php form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I run an application that shortens urls for authenticated users. The form for this application is simply an input for the full url, which then spits out a shortened url.

I would like to build a button that can be added to generated pages (the urls are long and messy) and once clicked would automatically submit the url shortening form.

The url shortening application is run in php. I've read a little bit about using ajax to submit the form. Does this matter if it's on a different website? Does anyone have a good tutorial or starting point for this sort of thing?

Many thanks!

edit to include code:

```
<form action=""  method="post">
  <label for="form_url">Which URL do you want to shorten?</label>
  <input type="url" id="form_url" name="form[url]" required="required" value="http://">
  <input type="hidden" name="form[_token]">
  <button type="submit" role="button">Shorten URL</button>
</form>



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.btn').click(function() {
  var pathname = window.location;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://url',
    data: $(pathname).serialize,
    success: success,
    dataType: text
  }); 
});
});
```

Comment: This can absolutely be done with `$.ajax()`. However, if the form is on a different website, then how are you appending this button to the 'generated pages'? I'm a bit confused. If you could clarify that point I'm sure we could help.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, That's awesome to hear and I appreciate the feedback that I'm at least heading in the right direction.

I work on this application and another co-worker works on the application we want to append this button to.

Comment: So you want to put this button on pages external to the form? Then return the shortened url to the page where the button is submitted?

Comment: @RussellBevan, that's correct.

Comment: Then you have the right idea. You need to make sure your php returns the result and then in your success function you can retrieve the data and assign it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to go on, considering you didn't post any code, but what I think you're asking is:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="long_url"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Now in the Javascript, you'd capture the submit event and call and ajax request:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "urlOfPhp",
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        success: function(returned_data) {
            // Handle Success Here.
        }
    }).error(function(){
        // Handle an Error Here.
    });
});
```

And that's the basics of Ajax. I'm also not clear on the Generated pages button thing, but this is a good starting point.

Comment: I think I have something similar. I've edited my original post to include the code.

Comment: @Moose print out your returned data and post it back here

Comment: @RussellBevan, I guess I'm a little confused. How do I specify that the current page url should be added to the input and then submitted? There is only one input in my app for the url, but does it need to specified to say, "hey put that variable (the long messy url) in to it before "submitting" the form?

So far none of my tests are working.

Comment: That's what you put in the `data` for your ajax request. Data is what gets sent for the php to process. Then you would get the post variables in your php, convert them and do a `echo json_encode($return);` which you could then get in your jQuery `success` function

Comment: Here's the order of Events: Complete Form->Press Submit->Interrupt Submit(e.preventDefault())->Serialize Data($("#myForm").serialize())->Send Data to Php Page->Use Data on Php Page->Return Data->Success Function

Comment: @TimLewis I'm still having problems because I'm not sending form information, I'm just sending the url which I've set in a variable and am just getting via jquery, this doesn't seem to be a problem though as long as I .serialize it. I think it's still not working because I'm using a php framework for the app (which I didn't write) and I can't find the functions.php page that processes the form submission for the url shrinking. Any clues on to find that? Should I just be using `http://domain.com/keywords/new?temporary` which is the public facing url?

Comment: The variable you set is in a form, therefore it is form information that you want to send. Regardless, what framework are you using? Generally it's a combination of something like `routes.php` and `SomethingController.php`

Comment: @TimLewis, How would you use a combination of the route and controller? I'm using Symfony2 if that helps.